# Routing & message handlers: request processing order issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm facing an issue with the execution order of the ASP.NET Web API request pipeline.

According to the ASP.NET Web API documentation (available [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers)), global message handlers are supposed to be executed before the routing mechanism.

[image: Request pipeline]

On this image, `MessageHandler1` is a global message handler whereas `MessageHandler2` is specific to *Route 2*.

---

I created a very simple example to show that there seems to be an issue in the execution order… or I'm really missing something important.

I have this controller

```
public class FooController : ApiController {
    [HttpPut]
    public string PutMe() {
        return Request.Method.Method;
    }
}
```

It only accepts `PUT` requests.

The application is configured as such:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    var configuration = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

    configuration.MessageHandlers.Add( new SimpleMethodOverrideHandler() );
    configuration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Foo",
        routeTemplate: "api/foo",
        defaults: new { controller = "foo", action = "putme" },
        constraints: new { put = new HttpPutOnlyConstraint() }
    );
}
```

`SimpleMethodOverrideHandler` is a very simple `DelegatingHandler` that just changed the request's method according to a `"method"` parameter in the query string.

```
public class SimpleMethodOverrideHandler : DelegatingHandler {
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync( HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken ) {
        var method = request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString()["method"];
        if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( method ) ) {
            request.Method = new HttpMethod( method );
        }
        return base.SendAsync( request, cancellationToken );
    }
}
```

So basically, requesting `/api/foo?method=put` in my browser would fire up `FooController`'s `PutMe` method.
Indeed, as seen earlier, the message handler treats the requests before it gets passed to the `HttpRoutingDispatched`.

Finally, here's how the the constaint `HttpPutOnlyConstraint` is defined:

```
public class HttpPutOnlyConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint {
    public bool Match( HttpRequestMessage request,
                       IHttpRoute route,
                       string parameterName,
                       IDictionary<string, object> values,
                       HttpRouteDirection routeDirection ) {
        return request.Method == HttpMethod.Put;
    }
}
```

---

Well the problem is that when I request `/api/foo?method=put` within my browser, the program first enters `HttpPutOnlyConstraint`'s `Match` method, which is wrong.

If we refer to the previously linked image, the message handler is supposed to be executed first, unfortunately it is not.

So, of course, `Match` returns `false` and no controller/action is found for the request, 404 happens.

If I remove the constraint from the route definition, the program enters `SimpleMethodOverrideHandler`, the request's method gets changed successfully and it is able to match and execute my controller's method.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a secret configuration parameter to know in order to do such things? :-)

If anyone needs the whole project, it's available [here [7KB zip file]](http://pk.am/b/WebApplication1.zip).

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know enough about this to post an answer, but think it could be useful for you to look at the source for RouteMagic (at https://github.com/Haacked/RouteMagic). It uses a dynamically registered handler to intercept routes, but also has some other routing features you may take inspiration from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing routing engine with Web API pipeline. `HttpRoutingDispatcher` is not a routing engine concept. The route constraints will be processed first because your underlying host needs to build a route table and match the route for your request.

`HttpRoutingDispatcher` is simply another implementation of `HttpMessageHandler` and all it does is it examines the `IHttpRoute` of the route that has been matched, and chooses which message handler to call next. If there is no per-route handler present, it delegates the processing to `HttpControllerDispatcher`.