# Form submit not triggering method from controller

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of users that i will add the ability to remove users from but with what i currently have - the form is not doing what it is supposed to do: that is to trigger the delete method from the api controller. I am not getting any errors on the page nor in the console and not sure what i could be doing wrong:

```
<form  data-submit-button="#userRemoveSubmit"  id="userRemoveForm" action="/api/UserRemove/" class="ajax" method="delete" data-overview-id="@ViewBag.OverViewID" data-bind="attr: { 'data-user-id': ID(), 'data-type-id': TypeId() }">
    .......
</form>

<a id="userRemoveSubmit" title="Remove User"><b>REMOVE</b></a>
```

Controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(TypesList typeInfo)
{
 ........
}
```

TypeList Model:

```
public class TypesList
{
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public int TypeId { get; set; }
  public int? OverViewId { get; set; }
}
```

How can i properly make them all connect together so that when i click on remove it triggers the delete method in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AJAX, and send a DELETE request:

```
$('#userRemoveSubmit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(),
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/UserRemove/',
        type: 'DELETE',
        data: { typeInfo : YOURVARIABLEHERE }
    }).done(function() {
         alert( "success" );
    })
    .fail(function() {
         alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
         alert( "complete" );
    });
});
```

ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i will go ahead and give this a try but i was wondering if i am properly passing in my parameters?

Comment: Updated, as you are typically passing a value to you DELETE Web Api. Also included `e.preventDefault()`, which will prevent the form from submitting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is th `action="delete"` in the form tag.

> Browsers usually can only perform GET or POST for the form elements
>   (unless you are submitting it using AJAX).

Please take a look at this answer so you can see a workaround:
[DELETE method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389514/delete-method-not-working)